# Ignore whitespace, Ignore punctuation, Microsoft office find and replace

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, microsoft-word-2010, find, find-and-replace

When selecting "Use wildcards" in microsoft word find and replace, the option to not "Match Case" becomes greyed out, as wildcard searches are case sensitive.  However, the options to ignore whitespace or punctuation remain selectable.

It appears however that this actually doesn't do anything when wildcards are enabled. Am I missing something here or was this an oversight by microsoft?

for example:
I am not able to match `example     string` or `example , string` with either the search queries `example string` or `example?string` in wildcard mode.  It seems these options do nothing at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somebody found this bug in 2008 in MS Word 2007. It is described as issue 3 under below link:

[Wild card characters are not working as expected in MS word 2007](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/microsoft.public.word.application.errors/E1MKublWlYc)

The discussion reveals some unclear historical (2003) background related to Japanese. It looks like the person who found this planned to report a bug, but was kindly persuaded that it doesn't make much sense.

Comment: And 8 years later, here we are...